# Count number of words in each sentence in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word I would like to be able to figure out how many words are in each sentence; specifically if any sentences have more than 20 words.

Is there a way to view such a statistic in MS Word? I'm aware of the readability statistics exist but doesn't give me the information I want.

Comment: I don't think there would be a build in way for that. You may try macros.

Comment: Normally I'm all for automation, but this is simple enough that it shouldn't warrant automation as a necessity, right?  Just take total words and divide by punctuation marks, e.g., <word count> / ("." + "!" + "?").

Answer (score 0):

This short macro will loop through each sentence, and if it is 20 words or more will highlight it green, so you can easily identify them and review.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count

For j = 1 To i

    If ActiveDocument.Sentences(j).Words.Count >= 20 Then ActiveDocument.Sentences(j).HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen

Next

End Sub
```